# omnet++ crashes while creatng objects

Tags: c++, omnet++

I have this piece of code.

```
tempIPARPReply = new IPv4ARP("IPv4ARPReply");                       
tempIPARPReply->setSourceIP(tempIPARP->getDestinationIP());
tempIPARPReply->setDestinationIP(tempIPARP->getSourceIP());
```

I have this in my header file.

```
IPv4ARP *tempIPARP;
```

Here `IPv4ARP` is my own created message in omnet.

It works perfectly fine.

But after I have project referenced the **inet** and **Core4Inet** projects to this working project on runtime the omnet++ simulation kernel simply crashes and ends with a simulation error. (And I have figured it out that simulation crash occurs only because of this object creation line as shown in the above code).

Please tell me what is going wrong here and how the referenced projects are impacting these 3 lines of code.

**Updated**:

msg File:

```
packet IPv4ARP {
    string SourceIP;
    string DestinationIP;
}
```

Comment: Could you show the definition of `IPv4ARP` (msg file)?

Comment: `IPv4ARP` msg file updated. Please check. Thanks.

Comment: One more thing. This code worked perfectly. But then I project referenced the `inet` and `core4inet` projects because I created new files that are dependent on this projects. Now after that my code crashes at this object creation line. Also note that `core4inet` is based on `inet`. And if I remove this two lines "tempIPARPReply->setSourceIP(tempIPARP->getDestinationIP());
tempIPARPReply->setDestinationIP(tempIPARP->getSourceIP());" and try to build then the `inet` projects `makefile` shows a `red` cross mark and i cannot proceed with run.

Comment: Do you use `inet` namespace in your code? If yes, try to add `namespace inet;` in `msg` file (just before `packet IPv4ARP {...`).